# Is it possible get URL value from where Value posted In PHP?

Tags: php, forms, post

I am working on a form POSTING value from a domain to another domain (for ex: `www.something1.com` to `www.something2.com`).

How can I validate that the request is posted from `www.something1.com`? or somewhere else.

- Is it possible to get the incoming request URL?
- Is there any other way of validating it?

Comment: [HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Short answer, you can't. Read about [server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).  If you see the part of 'HTTP_REFERER', that would be the only real way to, but a malicious user can change it.

Comment: @Jon can you explain how malicious user changes?

Comment: For that, I offer some reading, first one is non-malicious, the second is a firefox addon that makes changing the 'http_referer' incredibly easy. ^^ Part 1: http://www.secureworks.com/cyber-threat-intelligence/blog/research/21009/ Part 2: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/change-referer-button/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comments in answer form, as I don't believe that any current answers address your main issue.  You want to validate the source domain that the form appears on when it is submitted to another domain.

The short answer is **No**, you cannot validate it (at least for security reasons).  The option available that would give you the first domain would be `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, however, according to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

The problem resides in the fact that forms are submitted by the client, and *all* data sent to 'server2' can/will be modified by a malicious user to get around any security/validation you may have in place. The only other option would be to put some validation that needs to get submitted with the form, but the only way to make that anywhere close to effective would be to change it, and change it often. (ie, maybe every minute?).  But no matter what you add that needs to be submitted as well - a malicious user has full control over everything sent.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Some browsers may hide or spoof this header, but most will send it correctly.

However keep in mind that there is no way to guarantee correct referral, it is easy to fake.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the URL as a parameter "http://site.com/page2.php?prevUrl=".urlencode("http://site.com/page1.php").

hope it's help

Comment: Passing it as a parameter is as useless as 'http_referer' for a malicious user as it can be added by anyone trying to submit the form from a different source.